# Artifact of the black line in the client area

Tags: opengl, sdl-2

I have a black line artifact in the client area that disappears when the window is resized:

[image]

I called glViewport:

```cpp
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <iostream>

SDL_Window *window;
const float maxFPS = 5.f;

void fatalError(const std::string &message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    if (window)
    {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(-1);
}

int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize");
    }
    
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    const int winW = 300;
    const int winH = 300;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL, SDL2, C++",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        winW,
        winH,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!window)
    {
        fatalError("Failed to create the SDL window");
    }
    
    SDL_SetWindowResizable(window, SDL_TRUE);

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (!glContext)
    {
        fatalError("Failed to create the SDL_GL context");
    }

    if (!gladLoadGL())
    {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize the GLAD library");
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, winW, winH);
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.f, 1.f);
    
    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
                switch (event.window.event)
                {
                case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
                    glViewport(0, 0, event.window.data1, event.window.data2);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        float startTicks = SDL_GetTicks();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        // Limit FPS to the max FPS
        float frameTicks = SDL_GetTicks() - startTicks;
        if (1000.f / maxFPS > frameTicks)
        {
            SDL_Delay(1000.f / maxFPS - frameTicks);
        }
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

makefile

```
# build command: mingw32-make
# -mwindows - a key to hide the console

INC = -I"E:\Libs\SDL2-2.24.0-mingw-64bit\include" \
      -I"E:\Libs\glad-0.1.36-mingw-64bit\include"

LIB = -L"E:\Libs\SDL2-2.24.0-mingw-64bit\lib" \
      -L"E:\Libs\glad-0.1.36-mingw-64bit\lib"

all: main.o
    g++ main.o $(LIB) -lSDL2.dll -lglad -o app.exe

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c $(INC) main.cpp
```

The same topic on the official SDL2 forum: https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/artifact-of-the-black-line-in-the-client-area/39110

> Not sure if it matters but the
> [docs](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute) says you should
> call `SDL_GL_SetAttribute` before creating the window.

@Peter87 I tried it but everything the same:

```cpp
int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize");
    }
    
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    const int winW = 300;
    const int winH = 300;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL, SDL2, C++",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        winW,
        winH,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!window)
    {
        fatalError("Failed to create the SDL window");
    }
    
    SDL_SetWindowResizable(window, SDL_TRUE);

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (!glContext)
    {
        fatalError("Failed to create the SDL_GL context");
    }
```

Comment: We'll need a [mcve].

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/artifact-of-the-black-line-in-the-client-area/39110

Comment: Please add it to the question itself as text. I suspect this might be related to you not calling `glViewport()` on window resize. You need to give it the new window size every time it's changed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried but I cannot

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I called glViewport. I added a code. SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED does not called automatically after running. It must works from start without black lines.

Comment: Complete code please. Something we can compile and run ourselves.

Comment: I added a full code. But when I started this topic I could not make it because I had a message that I must to add more details.

Comment: I meant `glViewport` must be called on every resize, not once during initialization.

Comment: Yes, I understood. I had it before creating my topic. I deleted it before publish because I tried to make my example smaller to avoid the message "it seams you have code only, you should add more details". But now I can add the code. You can see that I added SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED. It does not effect.

Comment: Try passing `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` when creating the window, instead of calling `SDL_SetWindowResizable`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, it works! Thank you very much! It seams like it is a bug. Please, add your answer. I will mark it as solution.

Comment: Done. Please report this as a bug.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, done, I created the issue: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/6324

Comment: Thanks. Should probably also add the gif or screenshots there, to explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: You're right. I added it. You helped me a lot. Thanks again! I spent so much time on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a SDL bug, though for me the effect was different (the window wasn't resizable at all).

Instead of calling `SDL_SetWindowResizable(window, SDL_TRUE);`, pass `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` when creating the window.

Comment: I created the issue: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/6324